# Showing simple message dialogs

Tags: android

In my activity, I'd like to show simple info dialogs, stuff like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(message).show();
```

if I do that, the dialog will leak when I rotate that phone (not to mention it will disappear as well, so the user may miss it). I can use the managed dialogs, but I'm not sure how you use it sensibly for these types of short messages? Looks like you have to do this:

```
showDialog(SOME_DLG_ID);
...
@Override
onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == SOME_DLG_ID) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(message).show();
    }
}
```

there's no way to pass what the message should be into onCreateDialog since its an override method. I'd hate to make a member variable of the parent activity that just stores whatever the current message should be. How do you all do it?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are stuck with the member variable option... sorry.

Comment: yeah looks that way, what a shame! Thanks

Comment: Yup! That's a shame for developer. We need to code in such a weird pattern just to show up the dialog.

Answer (score 4):

> if I do that, the dialog will leak
>   when I rotate that phone (not to
>   mention it will disappear as well, so
>   the user may miss it)

You can add

```
<activity 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml to prevent restarting the activity when the phone rotates. I am using it in my app and my AlertDialog survives the rotation of phone.

Comment: yep, android:configChanges="orientation" is the way to go. it prevents the execution of "onCreate" and lets the app stay in the same state when rotating the phone

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `Activity.onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog)` to switch out the message before the dialog is shown on the screen.  So you could do something like:

```
@Override protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    if (id == SOME_DLG_ID) {
        ((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage(message);
    }
}
```

You'd still have to keep track of the message you're current showing in your activity, but at least this way, you're not creating a Dialog object for each message you want to show.

Comment: Well the problem here is the same, you can't pass the string message you have at the point you call showDialog() to onPrepareDialog or onCreateDialog()...

Comment: Ah, my bad... I suppose I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yeah and this is the main problem really, you need this weird pattern to get the dynamic message string to the dialog - it feels really awkward! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using DialogFragment to manage the dialog ensures that it correctly handles lifecycle events such as when the user rotates the screen or presses the Back button.