# Dialog.show() vs. Activity.showDialog()

Tags: android, dialog

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to show a Dialog from an Activity.

1. Create the Dialog (for example, using an `AlertDialog.Builder`), and then call the newly created Dialog's `show()` method.
2. Call the Activity's `showDialog()` method, passing in an int that uniquely defines what sort of Dialog you want to build. Then override `onCreateDialog()` to actually build the Dialog, and Android will display it for you.

The second method seems to be the standard practice but I'm curious if there is any reason it matters which one I use. Here's all I can come up with:

Reasons to use `Dialog.show`

1. If you need to parameterize the Dialog in some way, it can be a little awkward to use `Activity.showDialog`, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929556/showing-simple-message-dialogs). You may have to store a String or something in a member variable, just so that it can be retrieved moments later during `onCreateDialog` or `onPrepareDialog`.
2. The logic for creating and modifying the dialog is spread out across a number of places, potentially making the code harder to read and maintain:

   - The place where you call `showDialog()`
   - Inside a potentially large `switch` statement in the overridden `onCreateDialog` method
   - Inside a potentially large `switch` statement in the overridden `onPrepareDialog` method

Reasons to use `Activity.showDialog`:

1. The API docs for `Activity.showDialog` say that the Dialog is "managed" by the Activity which I suppose provides some benefit? But this is also true if you use the `AlertDialog.Builder`, I would think, because you pass in `this` as an argument to the Builder's constructor.
2. If your Activity is going to show the same (or a very similar) Dialog several times, this option creates it only once, instead of creating a new one each time, thus putting less strain on the system as far as allocating space for new objects, garbage collection, etc.

So my question is, what are the criteria for deciding when to use `Activity.showDialog` and when to use `Dialog.show`, and why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my opinion you should prefer `showDialog` because this method  will do most of the work for you. In example You don't have to worry that you will lose reference to your dialog after changing screen orientation. It will be recreated automatically. `Dialog.show` is much more prone to errors.

So I suggest you to use `showDialog` everywhere you can.

Comment: There is a detailed technical explanation on why we choose Activity.showDialog instead of Dialog.show. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/233010-dialogs-and-the-android-lifecycle/ Yup. Mostly deal related to screen orientation.

Comment: Just one point to note here: `onCreateDialog()` is only called once when the dialog first needs to be created and this is where you initially set the dialog's contents. If you need to update its contents, you should use `onPrepareDialog()` method, which is called just before each time the Dialog is displayed allowing you to update its contents propperly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the decision is up to you, depending on the good reasons you have pointed out. If I have an activity which has just one dialog (say, for displaying an alert) I'd just fire the `Dialog.show` method... on the other hand, if the UI of my app relies too much of its functionality on the use of dialogs it'd be much better to use `showDialog()`. I think the best advantage of using `showDialog()` is that it's easier to read:

```
final int ERROR_DIALOG = 404;
final int MSG_DIALOG = 200;

.....

// if someone else read this, he/she will immediately understand what's going on
showDialog( ERROR_DIALOG );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overloaded method [`showDialog(int, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) introduced in API level 8.
Simple shove the message to be shown into the bundle, which will be available in [`onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Yes, I know that `showDialog()` itself has been deprecated now.