# How should I use showDialog() and onDialogCreate() in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

I read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) document but don't understand.

It says I can use showDialog() to show a dialog and the system will call onDialogCreate().

But in the next section, it says I should use AlertDialog.Builder's create() to create a dialog.

I tried AlertDialog.Builer's show(), it works and a dialog popup. But... 
so where should I call showDialog() and onDialogCreate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the discussion : [Dialog.show() vs. Activity.showDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170308/dialog-show-vs-activity-showdialog)

Answer (score 1):

Lai Yu-hsuan.... They are saying that you may use AlertDialog.Builder.create to create a dialog and showDialog(int) to show the dialog that you create using myBuilder.create(). So in code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_MY:
        // do the work to define My Dialog
        dialog= getInstanceMyDialog();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

private AlertDialog getInstanceMyDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("MyMessage");
    AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("MyTitle");
    return alert;
}
```

You can then show the dialog as in:

```
this.showDialog(DIALOG_MY);
```

JAL