# How to call showDialog(i) from showDialog(i)? (Android)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my Android app, I have a dialog with a few options, one of which should result in the current dialog being displayed again.

It's like this:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    if (id == 0) {
        builder.setMessage("Message 0")
               .setPositiveButton("Show Message 0 Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       showDialog(0);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Show Message 1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       showDialog(1);
                   }
               });
    } else {
        builder.setMessage("Message 1")
               .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // nothing
                   }
               });
    }
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

However, when I click on the "Show Message 0 Again" button, the dialog is dismissed and does not appear again.  The "Show Message 1" button works fine.

I would prefer the dialog to actually be dismissed and then opened again, rather than simply having the "Show Message 0 Again" button just not do anything and not cause the dialog to be dismissed, if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the discussion : [Dialog.show() vs. Activity.showDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170308/dialog-show-vs-activity-showdialog)

Please Have a look on that...

Hopes it Helps. :)

Comment: So in this particular case, it's necessary to replace 'AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);' with 'final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);' and 'showDialog(0);' with 'builder.create().show();'.