# Activity.showDialog(int), Activity.removeDialog(int) deprecated

Tags: android

In this question [Dialog.show() vs. Activity.showDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170308/dialog-show-vs-activity-showdialog?rq=1)  it was recommended to use showDialog() that was 2010.  I need to support Android 2.1-4.1 so should I keep this deprecated code or change it? Reason for deprecation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android UI is now based on fragments, so you should use a DialogFragment.

It's included in the support library v4, so you can use it also in Android v2.1.

Blog post with example:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html